# What do the icons next to defeated opponents mean?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012

When you defeat an opponent, the game places a weird-looking sigil next to the opponent's portrait:

[image: Magic: the Gathering Sigils]

The colors might be hard to see, but the one to the left is bronze, and the two right ones are silver.

What do they mean? Do the colors represent the opponent's strength? How handily I trounced them? Something else?

> Note: this is for *Magic: The Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012*

Comment: Using old tag because [mtg-duels-of-planeswalker-2012] exceeds the 25 character tag limit.

Comment: Is it a substantially different game?

Comment: @Raven new game modes, new campaign system, new card set, new AI. Only thing similar is the name and the fact that you're playing *Magic: the Gathering*.

Comment: @Mark - is the Non - 2012 version of the game still available?

Comment: @Raven yes, it is.

Comment: I add the tag mtg-dotp-2012. I suppose we can use it beacause also Wizards.com refers to Duel of the Planeswalkers as DotP.

Comment: @Raven - Of note, if you have a PS3, the old one is free this month to PSN subscribers - which is EVERYBODY right now.

Comment: @Mark Incidentally, in case you don't know, that sigil is the Planeswalker symbol, which you can read more about [here](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/arcana/208) if you want more background on it in the context of the MtG universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon tells you what difficulty you have beaten that planeswalker on:

- Bronze is Mage
- Silver is Archmage
- Gold is Planeswalker

Comment: Hot dang, haven't played in a while, but I just tested and confirmed that this is what they mean. Very cool, thanks!

Comment: This answer **can't** be right.  I beat the entire regular campaign on Archmage *(I checked my difficulty several times throughout the campaign)*, and have bronze medals for every one.  I just beat one of the first Archenemy levels on Mage *(apparently... though I never changed it from Archmage)*, and we got a gold medal.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm not 100% on this, but my understanding (from the first game) is that the Icons indicate a rating of how well you've defeated that opponent.  They go from Bronze to Gold and are a function of remaining life, remaining cards in deck, and number of turns played.

Unfortunately, I haven't played the 2012 yet, so I can't confirm this for the second game

Comment: On the xbox, confirmed for 2012... although i don't know how they are judged exactly.